# Stop Fixed header on birdseye weebly theme and make logo larger

Tags: html, css, header, weebly

In refrence to: http://meraxcapital.weebly.com/

I'm Attempting to stop the sticky header in a weebly theme for a client but it is driving me nuts here is the basic header css code:

```
/* Header */
.birdseye-header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 12;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 250ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 250ms ease;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}
 .birdseye-header .container {
  display: table;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 80px;
}
 .birdseye-header label.hamburger {
  display: none;
}
.birdseye-header .logo {
 display: table-cell;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 margin-right: 30px;
 padding: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: normal;
}
.birdseye-header .logo a {
 display: block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: normal;
 }
 .birdseye-header .logo img {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 40px;
}
.birdseye-header .logo #wsite-title {
  display: block;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 40px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: normal;
  }
```

I have tried all ~logical~ methods, but any suggestions welcome.

I am also coming across some strife trying to enlarge the logo (same piece of code as above)

I have attempted changing the 'max-width / height elements and while that works with faffing around in inspect element it doesn't when actually implemented!

Thankyou so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is to disable the "fixed" position and change it to absolute. If you have access to the styles then I would change them directly from fixed to absolute. If not then you can try overriding what is there with the following:

```
.birdseye-header, body.page-has-banner.affix .birdseye-header, body.splash-page.affix .birdseye-header {
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

As for the image size... You need to disable or change the max-width and max-height on ".birdseye-header .logo img" selector.

You can try overriding them with the following:

```
body.page-has-banner .logo img {
     max-height: 70px;
     max-width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Joseph! Such a straightforward fix, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to stop the header from being fixed to the top of the web page you will have to remove the following:

```css
.birdseye-header {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Also you should remove the height - this some how adds height to the header - I think its in your main_style.css line/30:

```css
body.page-has-banner.affix .birdseye-header, body.splash-page.affix .birdseye-header { 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  background: rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.95); 
  /* height: 60px; */
  padding: 10px 30px; 
}
```

Comment: FYI - Merely removing the fixed property from .birdseye-header ends up pushing his banner image down which may not be what the asker is looking to accomplish.

Comment: I see what you mean - setting to position: absolute !important; would be best - as for the height of the logo there may be some other style that you have set effecting the logo styles